# Why these codes have different results in browser and in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just start learn javascript。 I found  these codes will have results when in browser and in run with node .

```
function Foo() {
    this.getName = function () { console.log(1); };
    return this;
} 
Foo.getName = function () { console.log(2);};
Foo.prototype.getName = function () { console.log(3);};
var getName = function () { console.log(4);};
function getName() { console.log(5);}
Foo.getName();  //2
getName();  //4
Foo().getName(); //1
getName();  //4
new Foo.getName(); //2
new Foo().getName(); //1
new new Foo().getName(); //1
```

and in browser the codes are as belows

```
function Foo() {
    getName = function () { alert (1); };
    return this;
}
Foo.getName = function () { alert (2);};
Foo.prototype.getName = function () { alert (3);};
var getName = function () { alert (4);};
function getName() { alert (5);}
Foo.getName();
getName();
Foo().getName();
getName();
new Foo.getName();
new Foo().getName();
new new Foo().getName();
```

I just wonder how this happens?

Comment: because `alert` is blocking while `console.log` isn't

Comment: `this` works differently in node.